# Why "alter table drop constraint" is executed before running table creation DDL with HSQLDB

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

I intended to make use of Spring 4 and Hibernate with HSQLDB to create a in memory database with the assumption that each word has exactly one part of speech just for testing purpose.

I have two entity classes:

```
public class Word {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  private String word;

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="PARTOFSPEECH_ID", insertable=false,updatable=false)
  private PartOfSpeech partOfSpeech;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getWord() {
    return word;
  }

  public void setWord(String word) {
    this.word = word;
  }

  public PartOfSpeech getPartOfSpeech() {
    return partOfSpeech;
  }

  public void setPartOfSpeech(PartOfSpeech partOfSpeech) {
    this.partOfSpeech = partOfSpeech;
  }
}
```

and

```
public class PartOfSpeech {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;
  private String partOfSpeech;
  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getPartOfSpeech() {
    return partOfSpeech;
  }

  public void setPartOfSpeech(String partOfSpeech) {
    this.partOfSpeech = partOfSpeech;
  }
}
```

With the code above I run the Spring with Hibernate and saw a very strange   `WARN`:

```
Hibernate: alter table Word drop constraint FKp318rmy36es1v4gqwr8nkaxbs
Sep 01, 2017 8:42:09 AM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
```

...

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.WORD
  at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getUserTable(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileAlterTable(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileAlter(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
  at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
  ... 111 more
```

I just can not understand why when the `@ManyToOne` and `@JoinColumn` annotations are added to the `Word` entity, the first SQL statement executed by the hibernate is `alter table Word drop constraint` out of my expectation :(

So anyone can help on this? How to remove the `alter table` pre-statement so that the obnoxious `WARN` stack trace disappear?

Comment: you seem to have omitted your JPA configuration that defines what schema operations are performed.

Comment: I also thought about this. The schema is PUBLIC by default, but the problem is that initially the table WORD does not exist in any case. So I don't think that is the cause

Comment: and the JPA configuration would tell anybody reading here WHAT you have configured to happen, but they dont see it. So you can think the cause is whatever you want but unless you give the key info then no help will be forthcoming.